# jQuery: Replace $ (currency symbol) to another currency symbol

Tags: jquery, str-replace

Im looking for function that will allow me to replace all dollar symbols within a div to "CHF" (another currency). The reason is that the currency symbol is hardcoded and it should be replaced.

Is there a simple way of doing this?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
jQuery('div').each(function(i){ jQuery(this).text(jQuery(this).text().replace('$','CHF')) })
```

Comment: Note, slight modification. I changed it to use .text() instead of .html(), since technically you only want to update the div text contents, not the attributes, script tags, etc.

Comment: Note, that using this example ALL div tag elements are going to be processed. This may slow down your page load, in some cases significantly. Whenever possible, it's advisable to replace such common tag with a more specific selector.